# regular expression ignore sign of digit

Tags: regex

i'm learning regular expressions at the moment and I try to grab a floating-point number. I like to discard all characters in front and back of the first floating-point number. 
at the moment I have this expression:

```
[\s\w]*([-+]{0,1}\d*[,.]{0,1}\d*)
```

and here are the cases that I like to match (the lines with an X are nit working)

```
'1,2'    ->  1,2   
'abc1,2' ->  1,2  
'   1,2' ->  1,2  
'  +1,2' -> +1,2  
'  -1,2' -> -1,2  
' --1,2' -> -1,2  X  
' +-1,2' -> -1,2  X  
' -+1,2' -> +1,2  X  
'    ,2' ->   ,2
'     1' ->  1
```

How to ignore the second sign in front of the digit?

Comment: You should learn to use `?` instead of `{0,1}`. `?` means "optional"

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Replace first `\d*` with `\d+`.

Comment: Are you trying to extract a decimal number, or to replace all that is not a decimal number?

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov this works, but in this case it is not possible to match this ',2' I forgot this in my list

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte I try to extract a floating-point number

Comment: @wenndemann: in this case the second example is impossible since you can't transform the character `.` into a `,`. Other question, do you want to include integers?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte ok the replacement is easy to do in a second step later on. Yes Integers are a must have

Answer (score 0):

Use `[-+]*` to match any number of sign characters, instead of just 1. And if you don't want them in the result, they should not be in the capture group.

```
[\s\w]*[-+]*(\d*[,.]{0,1}\d*)
```

Comment: He needs the - sign in his capture group according to his 6th example

Comment: But not according to the 5th example.

Comment: a '+' in the output is also be fine

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this. The pattern `[-+]*` will eat up all the sign characters, so there won't be any left to be matched by `[-+]?` inside the capture group. Making it non-greedy doesn't help, because the sign inside the capture group is optional. I can't think of a way to say that the last sign in the sequence should be saved for the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to extract the decimal numbers (including relative integers), you don't need to describe what happens before and after the number. So this should suffice:

```
[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?
```

Note: this pattern doesn't deal with cases like `.2` or `2.`, but it is easy to change this with an alternation *(writing `[+-]?\d*[.+]?\d*` is indeed not possible since it allows empty strings or a single sign or a single dot)*:

```
[+-]?(?:\d+(?:[.,]\d*)?|[.,]\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?:\w\s)*([+-]?(?:\d+[,.]?\d*|[,.]?\d+))
```

Comment: You may want to add an explanation to your solution.